# How to read apache flink jobmanager configuration from the job (application)

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to read the jobmanager configuration from my flink job, but couldn't find how to access that. Is there any way to read the configuration from the flink job?

For reference, I am trying to read the config that we see at `http://url/#/jobmanager/config`

Comment: Using the res-api sounds like a valid approach. Doesn't that worked out?

Comment: Yes that could probably work, I was looking if there is a way to get this without making a network call. Thanks!